# Twillio hanging up too early on forwarded call

Tags: twilio, voicemail

I am forwarding calls really simply....

http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=7702345678

My problem is that the calls are hanging up at around 6 rings and not allowing my cell service to send them to voice mail.

Anyone have a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code here instead of in a link? Links get broken and we want the question to be useful to future users.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

By default the forward twimlet sets the `<Dial>` verbs timeout to 20 seconds.  If you need a longer timeout you can set that in the twimlet:

```
http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=7702345678&Timeout=60&
```

Hope that helps.